# ¿Cómo recorrer un array en PHP para usarlo en un V-select de VueJS?

Tags: php, backend, phalcon

Necesito recorrer un array para mostrarlo en un v-select de VueJS, al momento de crear el array este se crea correctamente .

Esta es la funcion para crear el ARRAY

```
public function getAction()
    {
      $payrollTypes = array(
        ['payrolltype' => 'NOMINA'],
        ['payrolltype' => 'VACACIONES'],
        ['payrolltype' => 'PRIMA'],
        ['payrolltype' => 'DEFINITIVAS']
      );
      $this->JsonResponseAction(array('data' => $payrollTypes));
    }
```

Esto me retorna la funcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de Seleccionar una de las opciones del Array en el Select no lo selecciona, solo toma el ultimo valor del array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quiero seleccionar alguna de las otras opciones no la reconoce

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo realice de esta manera y me funciono correctamente.

```
public function getAction()
    {
      $payrollTypes = [
        ['id' => 1, 'payrolltype' => 'NOMINA'],
        ['id' => 2, 'payrolltype' => 'VACACIONES'],
        ['id' => 3, 'payrolltype' => 'PRIMA'],
        ['id' => 4, 'payrolltype' => 'DEFINITIVAS'],

    ];
```

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, con que la marques como lo hiciste, basta. Recuerda que acá abajo sólo van los intentos de respuesta (así que puedes **añadir** esto como edición a tu pregunta, por ejemplo).

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto

```
public function getAction()
{
    $payrollTypes = [
        'NOMINA',
        'VACACIONES',
        'PRIMA',
        'DEFINITIVAS'
    ];
    
    $this->JsonResponseAction(['data' => $payrollTypes]);
}
```

Buena suerte!

Comment: Buena respuesta. Recuerda, eso sí, acompañar tu código sugerido con algún breve comentario explicando por qué esto resuelve el problema o cómo debería usarse este código. Piensa siempre que te van a leer otros con el mismo problema en el futuro